# Can't loop in Table Rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

The conditions to apply a given action to each table row are :

- contains the word "keyword"
- value attribute of input tag equals to "2"

With [this code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qONQwx), it works only with the ***first*** row :

```
$('table.tab-shopping-cart > tbody > tr.hproduct').each(function () {
        var qtty = $('input.basketstep_update').val();
        var product = $('td.col-description a').text().indexOf("keyword"); 
        if (product >=0 && qtty == 2) { 
        $(this).css('background-color','green') // dumb action to the row
        }
})
```

HTML

```
<table class="tab-shopping-cart">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="hproduct">
            <td class="col-description"><a>keyword</a></td>
            <td class="col-qty">
                <div>
                    <input class="basketstep_update" value="3">
                </div>
            </td>           
        </tr>
        <tr class="hproduct">
            <td class="col-description"><a>keyword</a></td>
            <td class="col-qty">
                <div>
                    <input class="basketstep_update" value="2">
                </div>
            </td>           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should supply a context to restrict those finders:

```
var qtty = $('input.basketstep_update', this).val();
var product = $('td.col-description a', this).text().indexOf("keyword");
```

... or, slightly better:

```
var $row = $(this);
var qtty = $row.find('input.basketstep_update').val();
var isProduct = $row.find('td.col-description a').text().indexOf("keyword") !== -1;
if (isProduct && +qtty === 2) {
  $this.css('background-color','green');
}
```

Otherwise the whole DOM will be searched for the elements matching the selectors, and the very first element of the findings will be used (that's why it works only for the first row - it contains those firsties).

Comment: That's very clear, thank you and every fellow who contributed. Didnt know about the context parameter inside the jquery search !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helpFul

```
  $('table.tab-shopping-cart > tbody > tr.hproduct').each(function () {

         var $currentRow = $(this);
         var qtty = $currentRow .find('input.basketstep_update').val();
         var product = $currentRow .find('td.col-description a').text().indexOf("keyword");

            if (product >=0 && qtty == 2) { 
                $currentRow.css('background-color','green') // dumb action to the row
            }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with below code:
$('table.tab-shopping-cart > tbody > tr.hproduct').each(function () {
        var qtty = $(this).find('input.basketstep_update').attr('value');
        var product = $("td.col-description a:contains('keyword')"); 
        if (product && qtty == 2) { 
            $(this).css('background-color','green') // dumb action to the row
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you are missing the context of each loop with `this` but you can use with `.css()` using  a callback function:

```js
 $('table.tab-shopping-cart > tbody > tr.hproduct').css('background-color', function() {
   var qtty = $('input.basketstep_update', this).val();
   var product = $('td.col-description a', this).text().indexOf("keyword");
   if (product >= 0 && qtty == 2) {
     return 'green' // return dumb action to the row
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tab-shopping-cart">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hproduct">
      <td class="col-description"><a>keyword</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col-qty">
        <div>
          <input class="basketstep_update" value="3">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hproduct">
      <td class="col-description"><a>keyword</a>
      </td>
      <td class="col-qty">
        <div>
          <input class="basketstep_update" value="2">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to go is by using parseInt() for `val()` and also use the context selector within the `each`.
Also remember to use `===` and not `==` when doing such comparison.

```
$('table.tab-shopping-cart > tbody > tr.hproduct').each(function() {
  var qtty = parseInt($(this).find('input.basketstep_update').val(), 10);
  var produitpneu = $(this).find('td.col-description a').text().indexOf("Pneu");
  if (produitpneu !== -1 && qtty === 2) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **data** to simplify your code

```
$('.tab-shopping-cart .hproduct').each(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  var qtty = $row.find('.basketstep_update').val();
  if ($row.data('type') === 'pneu' && qtty == 2) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green')
  }
})
```

So your HTML looks like

```
  <table class="tab-shopping-cart">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="hproduct" data-type="pneu">
        <td class="col-description"><a>Pneu</a></td>
        <td class="col-qty">
          <div>
            <input class="basketstep_update" value="3">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hproduct" data-type="pneu">
        <td class="col-description"><a>Pneu</a></td>
        <td class="col-qty">
          <div>
            <input class="basketstep_update" value="2">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also, avoid selector too strict, like `table.foo` or even `div.bar > div.foo > div.bar` it's too complicate, and your HTML could not change in the future.